# Click on a link with phantom.js and retrieve the document html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, phantomjs

I'm new with phantom.js and I'm trying to navigate on a website page, to click on a link (that calls an AJAX function and changes the document HTML) with phantom.js.

Here is my code:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    phantom.exit();
}, 120000);

var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open("http://example.com", function(status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('{"error":"Unable to load the address for page"}');
        phantom.exit();
    }

    var action = page.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById("anID").click();
        return "clicked";
    });

    var results = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    });

    console.log(action);

    window.setInterval(function() {
        console.log(results);
        phantom.exit();
    }, 3000);
});
```

I'm very confusing as in my "action" function, the click() call is raising that error repeated 3 times:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
>   phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():3 phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
>   ph.js:121 null
>
> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
>   phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():3 phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
>   ph.js:121 null
>
> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
>   phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():3 phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
>   ph.js:121 null

Also, if I comment the line when I send a click, the action function does not raise an error anymore and returns well the "clicked" console log. But 3 times...

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI you have 2 semi-colons after this line: `document.getElementById("anID").click();;`

Comment: Yes thanks it's a mistake when posting it here, problem still there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally managed to achieve my task with this code. I skipped the click action and went directly to the AJAX call:

```
    // phantomjs test.js 'http://www.example.com' 'anID'

    var system = require('system');
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    var url = system.args[1];
    var target = system.args[2];

    page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) { 
        console.log(msg); 
        phantom.exit();
    };

    page.open(url, function (status) {
            function evaluate(page, func) {
                var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 2);
                var fn = "function() { return (" + func.toString() + ").apply(this, " + JSON.stringify(args) + ");}";
                return page.evaluate(fn);
            }
            page.injectJs('jquery-1.7.2.min.js');
            if (status === 'success') {
                    evaluate(page, function(target) {
                        $.ajax({
                          type: 'POST',
                          url: document.URL,
                          data: "__EVENTTARGET=" + target,
                          success: function(msg){
                                console.log(msg);
                            }
                        });
            }, target);
        }
    });
```